# Checking for internet connection in runtime

Tags: delphi

In which event or how can i check for internet connections while program is running? Scenario: program is running and suddenly internet connection goes off and a dialog opens "No internet access, changing connection string to central database". I tried this function, but im not sure in which event should i put so that it works all the time.

```
function TFK_Lib.CheckInternet: boolean;
begin
  ConnectedState := INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM;
  Result := InternetGetConnectedState(@ConnectedState, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Your proposed solution isn't going to work. Suppose that the connection drops after you call `CheckInternet`, but before you go on to use the connection. There's a race condition here that you need to acknowledge.

Comment: AFAIK above function will not even give you current connection state. It will only indicate that Internet connection is properly configured, but not its current active/non-active state.

Comment: I think you are not interested in formal internet status - Windows might think it is connected, but your program has no access to exactly your remote database (remote DB server down, intranet instead of internet, firewall antivirus blocking your application, whatever other problem).
Alternatively, you may have no connection to WWW, but still have connection to your database online. So, you only have to try connecting to your particular remote service and report any error text that Windows would give you in case of failure. It's not interesting to your app if some Large Internet is avail or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to check (at a time period) the connection and show the dialog (as a modal so you can't do anything else).

Answer (score -1):

You can do a practical test and ping google.com. 
If I understood your question correctly I thinks its not a bad option.
Code example:

```
class function TAuthUserFunctions.CheckInternet: boolean;
    var
     idtcp : TIdTCPClient;
    begin
      try
        idtcp := TIdTCPClient.Create(Nil);
        try
          idtcp.ReadTimeout := 2000;
          idtcp.ConnectTimeout := 2000;
          idtcp.Port := 80;
          idtcp.Host := 'google.com';
          idtcp.Connect;
          idtcp.Disconnect;
          Result := True;
        finally
          idtcp.Free;
        end;
      except
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea! Google won't certainly like this ;)

Comment: Well, it will still endure :)

Comment: First of all, Windows have function for checking connection to specific url `InternetCheckConnection` and, second, pinging Google is ultimately bad idea.

Comment: `InternetCheckConnection()` and `InternetGetConnectedState()` are known to be unreliable, reporting wrong results at times. The only reliable solution is to ping/connect to an external server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but surely one should just try to connect to whatever it is they're trying to connect to in the first instance.  This tells us nothing except that we can ping google.